# Prevent popup from being transparent

Tags: html, css

I'm really not sure what this would be called but when I have a popup showing this happens. I also am not sure why I get a thumbs down for asking a legit question.

[image]

Notice how the checkbox below it is bleed through and also I can see the header column underneath that also. How can I prevent that?

This is my css for that popup

```
.help-tip{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#d1d1d2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
    display:block;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;

    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

**.help-tip p{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 340px;       
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    right: -4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}**

.help-tip p:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    right:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Put your HTML in your question please.

Comment: Just add `z-index: 1000;` to your tool tip, so it renders above the content.

Comment: I'm confused it is  in the question. Can you not see it?

Comment: Can we also get the HTML for your popup and the page? From first glance it looks like you need to set your z-index of the popup higher than that of the checkbox.

Comment: skobaljic can you create this is an answer so I can mark it complete and give you credit. This did work by the way thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers create objects in the order they appear in the HTML. With each new object being created in-front of all previous objects. This usually isn't an issue as your content flows down the page rather than overlapping.

However, with popups, you want to overlap content, so you start showing some things out of order, meaning that objects created later can be above or on top of earlier objects.

There are 2 ways to solve your particular problem.
1) Move the popup to further down in your HTML document (so that it is created after, and exists above other content), or 
2) Use z-index css property to specify where in the stack you would like your objects to appear (think of this like 'send to back'/'bring to front' used in Word)